# How to use a nested dictionary for breadth-first search?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, python-3.7

I have converted this text file:

```
BREST:
Rennes 244

RENNES:
Brest 244
Caen 176
Nantes 107
Paris 348

CAEN:
Calais 120
Nancy 534
Paris 297

NANCY:
Calais 534
Dijon 201
Paris 372
Strasbourg 145
```

into the following nested dictionary:

```
cities = {'BREST:': {'Rennes': 244},
          'RENNES:': {'Brest': 244, 'Caen': 176, 'Nantes': 107, 'Paris': 348},
          'CAEN:': {'Calais': 120, 'Paris': 241, 'Rennes': 176},
          'NANCY:': {'Calais': 534, 'Dijon': 201, 'Paris': 372, 'Strasbourg': 145}
          }
```

I am trying to use Breadth-first search to find the path from one city to another. I have to define the bfs function within a class called Node. This is the bfs function I am using:

```
from collections import deque

class Node:
    visited = []
    queue = []

    def bfs(self, visited, queue, graph, start):
       visited.append(start)
       queue.append(start)

       while queue:
           m = queue.pop(0)
           print(m, end=" ")

           for neighbor in graph[m]:
               if neighbor not in visited:
                   visited.append(neighbor)
                   queue.append(neighbor)
```

Whenever I run this code for the `start` node as 'RENNES:', I get this error:

```
line 99, in bfs
    for neighbor in graph[m]:
KeyError: 'Brest"
```

I am not sure why I keep getting this error message. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`cities` contain a number of syntax errors of the form:

```
'BREST:' ...
```

that should be:

```
'BREST': ...
```

The keys in `cities` are inconsistent.  The top-level dict uses all upper case letter keys, while the 2nd level dict uses title case. This is why `for neighbor in graph[m]` fails as you try look up the 'Brest' but it's called 'BREST'.  I used the same case below.

The `cities` data is also incomplete. There is an edge from Rennes to Nates but Nates is not listed at the top-level.  I now check for that.

```
cities = {
    'Brest': {'Rennes': 244},
    'Rennes': {'Brest': 244, 'Caen': 176, 'Nantes': 107, 'Paris': 348},
    'Caen': {'Calais': 120, 'Paris': 241, 'Rennes': 176},
    'Nancy': {'Calais': 534, 'Dijon': 201, 'Paris': 372, 'Strasbourg': 145}
}


def bfs(graph, start):
   visited = [start]
   queue = [start]
   while queue:
       m = queue.pop(0)
       print(m, end=" ")
       if m in graph:
           for neighbor in graph[m]:
               if neighbor not in visited:
                   visited.append(neighbor)
                   queue.append(neighbor)
   print('')


bfs(cities, 'Rennes')
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. How would I update the graph as I descent?